# How to add custom css class for each page?

Tags: asp.net, css, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Im a newbie in Orchard CMS and I cant find help in Google.

I want to assign a custom css class in every page. Like .
I tried using vandelay classy module but it doesnt seem to be working.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vandelay Classy does actually work, it's Orchard itself that has a bad implementation of `Content.cshtml`. If you override that template in your theme with the following, it should just work:

```
@using Orchard.Utility.Extensions;
@{
    if (Model.Title != null) {
        Layout.Title = Model.Title;
    }

    Model.Classes.Add("content-item");

    var contentTypeClassName = ((string)Model.ContentItem.ContentType).HtmlClassify();
    Model.Classes.Add(contentTypeClassName);

    var tag = Tag(Model, "article");
}
@tag.StartElement
    <header>
        @Display(Model.Header)
        @if (Model.Meta != null) {
            <div class="metadata">
                @Display(Model.Meta)
            </div>
        }
    </header>
    @Display(Model.Content)
    @if(Model.Footer != null) {
        <footer>
            @Display(Model.Footer)
        </footer>
    }
@tag.EndElement
```

I've patched 1.x so that 1.7 gets this out of the box and the override will no longer be necessary.

Comment: `Model.Classes.Add("content-item");

    var contentTypeClassName = ((string)Model.ContentItem.ContentType).HtmlClassify();
    Model.Classes.Add(contentTypeClassName);`

So this is the code that adds the classes?

Comment: Not exactly, that code is adding the regular Orchard classes, and the line after that, with the StartElement, is where the classes get actually rendered onto the tag. Classy adds its own classes before that, from CustomCssHandler.

Comment: Should Content.Summary.cshtml be altered in a similar way?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Vandelay.Industries

Comment: Yes, im already using this but it seems not displaying the classes I supplied to a certain page.